# what is the class com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableXmlSecurity in latest jersey versions

Tags: jersey, java-17, jersey-3.0

I am working on migration of a project which uses below jersey param
com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableXmlSecurity
I am not able to find a replacement for the same in latest jersey library which is compatible with jakarta namespace.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.40/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/message/MessageProperties.html#XML_SECURITY_DISABLE) property?